# Getting 401 Unauthorized with valid access token using identity server 4 with Asp.net Core API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, bearer-token, unauthorized, authorize-attribute

I am using Identity server 4 in my Asp.net core API Application , i am getting successful token on **local** server 
https://localhost:[port]/connect/token 
and it gives access token and when i use the bearer token to access authorize method then it **working fine** 
but **on server**
https://example.com/connect/token it also give successful token but when i use this token to access authorize method then it give **401 unauthorized error**

```
  "Authority": "https://example.com",
  "Audience": "https://example.com/resources",
  "RequireHttpsMetadata": "true"


 services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
          {
              options.Authority = configuration["AppSettings:Authority"];
              options.Audience = configuration["AppSettings:Audience"];
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AppSettings:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
          });
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityClaimsProfileService>();



    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };
    }
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        };
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        // client credentials client
        return new List<Client>
        {

            // resource owner password grant client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ro.angular",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding

            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Here is my identity server setting in "AppSettings": {
    "Authority": "https://example.com/",
    "Audience": "https://example.com/resources",
    "RequireHttpsMetadata": "true",

Comment: only one, that is tested on local then deployed on server (example.com)

Comment: There may be a configuration error. Can you verify the value of _Authority in your api_, possibly from your settings, something like: `options.Authority = configuration["AppSettings:Authority"];`.

Comment: In authority the value is identity server domain link eg. https://example.com

Comment: It's working , need to send correct scope in which user is registered eg. scope : api1 to generate token  https://prnt.sc/q3cqao

Answer (score 3):

This might be because of scope variable.

You have to follow these steps to check scope

1. Copy your token
2. Paste this on Jwt.io
3. After decoding your token find the scope and then generate the token with right scope.